# Write multiple iteration of a networkx graph into .graphml format

Tags: graph, networkx, graphml

I created a graph using the following code where I am getting **number of nodes** and **probability** as input from the user.

```
def my_erdos_renyi():
    erdos_renyi_nodes = int(input("Please enter the number of nodes"))
    erdos_renyi_probability = float(input("Please enter the value of probability"))
    G_erdos_renyi = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(erdos_renyi_nodes, erdos_renyi_probability)
    nx.draw(G_erdos_renyi, with_labels=True)
    plt.axis('on')
    plt.show()
my_erdos_renyi()
```

Later, I am writing this graph using

```
nx.write_graphml(G_erdos_renyi, "my_erdos_renyi.graphml")
```

Now, I want to generate and write 100 iterations of this random graph.
So I will run the code 100 times in **for loop** but how to write the logic to store graph with names such as
"my_erdos_renyi_1.graphml",

"my_erdos_renyi_2.graphml"

and so on till
"my_erdos_renyi_100.graphml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    nx.write_graphml(G_erdos_renyi, f"my_erdos_renyi_{i+1}.graphml")
```

Comment: Thank you @AveragePythonEnjoyer, I have tried your answer by adding a while loop to the graph function but it not working. Can you help me with this?

`itr=int(input("Please enter number of times for iteration: "))
x = 0
upper_limit = itr
while (x <= itr): # Looping condition
**My graph function**
   for i in range(itr):
     nx.write_graphml(G, f"G_{i + 1}.graphml")
 x = x+1`

Comment: why not try: `for i in range(itr): nx.write_graphml(G, f"G_{i + 1}.graphml")`

Comment: Yeah dear @AveragePythonEnjoyer, by moving the for loop, input statements before my function definition worked. I really appreciate your response.